# Why does MembershipProvider.GetUser consume so many resources how to ensure it uses the EF db context?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, membership-provider, membership

In our web application, we observed the following:

[image]

GetUser/CreatMembershipEntities/ExplicitLoadFromAssembly seems quite expensive.

Also noticing that CreateEntityConnection is being called - EntityFramework?

I'm not entirely convinced that EF was configured correctly for this application.  If it was, and was in use, I wouldn't expect to see new connections to be initiated for every call - yes/no?

Is a way to streamline this to avoid some major code refactoring?

The use of `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()` seems like a biggie here.  Instead of using the MembershipProvider to create users, what about just executing a sproc that does the same things.

I have found the following code that is ridiculous, as far as I am concerned - in causing a new call for each user until a unique one can be generated:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Integer.MaxValue
    'Generate unique username
    If System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(userName & i) Is Nothing Then
        'Increment value until no duplicate username found
        userName = userName & i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

-- UPDATE--

I have modified the question slightly...

We were able to run up to 20 users then the IIS server would tank.  Does the GetUser() method create a brand new connection every time?  It looks like it, based on the results.  How can I ensure that this GetUser() thing is actually using the db context, rather than spinning up its own connections?

Comment: Please use tracing mode of DotTrace instead of sampeling mode and post a updated screenshot that shows the number of times the methods are called.

Comment: Great... will do, thank you.

Comment: We ended up rolling our own, using the data structure that asp.net created.  It's an odd data structure to say the least.

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework

Comment: @Jeff - but this is a .Net Membership provider issue.

Comment: This is specifically an issue with the Entity Framework implementation of the ASP .NET MembershipProvider

Comment: So because we are using EF, `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()` uses this and causes all the overhead?